Group by first element, find ranges of second element
For a list like this (sorted by the first and then second elements):
[[1,3],[1,4],[1,5],[1,7],[1,8],[1,10],[3,5],[3,6],[3,8],…]

I would like a function that groups by the first element and gives ranges for the second element:
[[1,[(3,5),(7,8),10],[3,[(5,6),8]],…]


Is the input always sorted, and did you try anything?

So not then sorted by the second element, even though the example happens to be?

@Ry- Sorted by first then by second element.

@Ry- No, but some modification of this would seem could work.

Yep, it’s pretty much applying itertools.groupby and applying what you linked to each group.

Using functions map_reduce and consecutive_groups from module more_itertools:
from more_itertools import map_reduce, consecutive_groups
from operator import itemgetter

# MUST BE SORTED
l = [[1,3],[1,4],[1,5],[1,7],[1,8],[1,10],[3,5],[3,6],[3,8]]

def first_and_last(group):
    first = next(group)
    last = first
    for last in group:
        pass
    return (first, last) if last != first else first

def get_intervals(sorted_values):
    return list(map(first_and_last, consecutive_groups(sorted_values)))

r = map_reduce(l,
               keyfunc=itemgetter(0),
               valuefunc=itemgetter(1),
               reducefunc=get_intervals)

print(r)
# defaultdict(None, {1: [(3, 5), (7, 8), 10], 3: [(5, 6), 8]})


Is there a way to do it without more_itertools?

@Geremia You could define map_reduce and consecutive_groups by copying their sourcecode from https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/more_itertools/more.html#map_reduce and https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/more_itertools/more.html#consecutive_groups
